# BASH - Script isn't executing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script, cron

I have a bash script, which checks a .txt file once a minute, and calls another script, if necessary.

I am using `cron` for this, and this is in root's crontab;

```
* * * * * /home/****/scripts/protocol_checker.sh
```

The script, which is called by cron;

`cat protocol_checker.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

if grep -q "activate jammer" /etc/proto.txt; then
echo "`TZ=Turkey date` Calling jam.sh" >>/home/****/scripts/log/jam.log
./home/****/scripts/jam.sh
echo "`TZ=Turkey date` called jam.sh as `whoami`" >> /home/****/scripts/log/jam.log
```

I know it works properly, due to the log file:

```
Thu Jan  1 05:40:01 EET 1970 Calling jam.sh
Thu Jan  1 05:40:01 EET 1970 called jam.sh as root
```

and file permissions are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 **** ****  577 Oct  4 18:21 jam.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 **** ****  343 Oct  4 13:45 protocol_checker.sh
```

And here is the problem: When `protocol_checker.sh` executes, it should in turn execute jam.sh, but it doesn't. I even tried with just a simple `echo "hey"` line in `jam.sh`.  Everything looks fine for me? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you even try running the `protocol_checker.sh` script manually (and/or capturing ***all*** of its output when you ran it from `cron`)?  Did you notice the `./home/****/scripts/jam.sh: not found` error message?  You don't use `./` to run a script *in general*, you use it to run a program (script or compiled binary) ***in the current directory***; see [Problems when trying to execute sh file from another sh file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/196135/23408).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ./home/****/scripts/jam.sh

Change it to:

> . /home/****/scripts/jam.sh

Note there is a space after dot

Comment: @miyalys I'm guessing that he wants to source it instead of to execute directly.  :)